# macro defined in C++ dll and use the same in C#

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, macros

We have couple of macro which is defined in C++ DLL and we want to use it in C# dotnet 4.0.

Is it possible to use them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your favorite C# programming book for the #if directive.  No, text substitution is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# does not support macro's.
Convert your macro's to functions and use them.